# PHP Class 'ZipArchive' working OK in browser but not found in CLI mode

Tags: php, command-line-interface, php-ziparchive

So I have this script example.php:

```
<?php
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
```

if I call it from a browser it runs fine without any errors, but if I run it in CLI mode like this (from another php file):

```
<?php
echo system("php example.php");
```

I will see this output: *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/...*

I use scripts like this because I need to call them and run unattended and they are working fine until I needed to include the ZipArchive class.

Why it can't find the ZipArchive class in cli mode?

I mention that if I run from terminal `php example.php` it is also working fine.

I spend several hours already trying to figure out, it is driving me crazy. Your help is really appreciated.

*local server: XAMPP, PHP Version 7.4.25, macOS Big Sur*

Comment: Make sure that php executable you use in web server and command line is the same. In command line run `php -i | grep zip` for Linux, Mac, `php -i | findstr zip` for [Windows cmd](https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-grep-equivalent-cmd-powershell/).

Answer (score 1):

PHP CLI might have a different php.ini from what the "browser" version is using, so it might happen that an extension is enabled in one, but not in the other. I know this was the case in WAMP several years ago, so it might be the same in XAMPP too. Check what ini files are loaded by each version:

For the browser version:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

For PHP CLI:

```
php --ini
```

Comment: They are not the same...

---- Browser: Loaded Configuration File /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini

---- CLI: Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini

Comment: @Victor then search how the zip extension is enabled in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini` and do the same in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is crazy I see that I have 3 php versions running on my computer, 7.4.25 when I run from browser, 7.4.28 when I check from terminal, and a 7.3.29 when I call the script with exec/system (this one is not working with ZipArchive).